# Every time I tried to install through terminal this pop-up comes up. English language is not there

Tags: command-line, language-support

Every time I try to install through terminal this pop-up appears. English language is not there.

[image: screenshot of my terminal while installing applications]

Comment: Depends on what you install.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us some context. Start from the beginning: what Ubuntu are you running? What are you trying to install? What command did you run to get the image in the screenshot? What is the actual problem? Have you scrolled down and English isn't there? Do you even want to install in English? The more you explain, the better your chances of someone answering.

Comment: Use the down-arrow on your keyboard to scroll down?